# HttpContext null in WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

here is my line of code and it throws me error on `HttpConext.Current`

```
string postData = "username=" + HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode(USERNAME);
```

Comment: Where is this code placed? inside a WCF Service Data Contract?

Comment: the code placed inside the wcf service.svc.cs

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's normal. There is no HTTP Context in a WCF web service. A WCF service might not even be hosted inside a web server. You could host in inside a console application. There's a trick that allows you to set the [ASP.NET Compatibility Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx):

```
<system.serviceModel>        
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />    
</system.serviceModel>
```

but it is not something that I would recommend you doing.

I would do this instead:

```
var postData = "username=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(USERNAME);
```

And because I have a 7th sense about where you are going with this code (sending it as an HTTP request to a remote web server) let's get straight to the point:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "username", USERNAME }
    };
    var result = client.UploadValues("http://foo.com", values);
}
```

Comment: i am testing this service on my local machine is there no way ?

Comment: @Abu Hamzah, it doesn't matter, no HttpContext inside WCF service please.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to enable the HttpContext you can set the `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` flag in web config.

```
<system.serviceModel>        
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />    
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: The easiest way when WCF service is hosted in IIS.